# Foreign key POST in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have some problems with my app . I need to make task with relations to user.

Here is my code:

**bug**

```
 ValueError at /
Cannot assign "(<SimpleLazyObject: <function AuthenticationMiddleware.process_request.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x04C54E38>>,)": "Task.usertask" must be a "UserMembership" instance.
```

**models.py**

```
class UserMembership(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True,blank=True)
    image=models.FileField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/',null=True,blank=True)


class Task(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)
    is_published=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    usertask=models.ForeignKey(UserMembership, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    usertask = request.user,
    title = request.POST['title']
    task = Task(usertask=usertask,title=title)
    task.save()

task = Task.objects.order_by('-date').filter(is_published=True, usertask=request.user.id)

context={
    'task':task,
}
return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

**html form**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}

    <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">add</button>
```

Comment: In your definition of the Task class, I think you want settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL instead of UserMembership as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task model's usertask field related with UserMembership model as ForeignKey.So you must give a UserMembership object for create Task object. You gave request.user as usertask but request.user is'nt a UserMembership object.You must find UserMembership object before. You can use following code:

```
user_member_ship = UserMemberShip.objects.get(user=request.user)
Task.objects.create(title=title,usertask=user_member_ship)
```

Comment: I made some changes if I add new task I get following error:

Comment: `ValueError at /
Cannot assign "<UserMembership: lenovo>": "Task.usertask" must be a "User" instance.`

Comment: How do you create Task object? Can you share create line of your code?

Comment: `<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}

    <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">add</button></form>`

Comment: Sorry, I asked about python side codes. Task.objects.create... etc

Comment: Here is full post request I coded . Without user's stuff it is working. `if request.method == 'POST':
        # user_member_ship = UserMembership.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
        user_membership = UserMembership.objects.create(user=request.user)
        user_membership.save()

        title = request.POST['title']
        task = Task(title=title,usertask=user_member_ship)
        task.save()`

Comment: Firstly, your find usermembership code is wrong.Because you gave user key into get method but your value is user_id.You can use UserMembership.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id) or UserMembership.objects.get(user=request.user). After that, even create method creates a object. Using save() method is unneccesary.Could you try again after this editings?

Comment: **So , find a solution . But instead of UserMembership.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id) I put User.objects.get(id=request.user.id) ** but Thank you for helping me !

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1) in your views function you are doing this: `usertask = request.user`. Note that `request.user` will return a `User` object.

2) You then try to create a `Task` object by doing this `task = Task(usertask=usertask,title=title)` but here you have set `usertask` to a `User` object when you really need a `UserMembership` object

You can try rewriting your view function like so:

```
def MyViewFunction(request):

    # unpack request:
    user = request.user
    title = request.POST['title']

    # create new UserMembership object:
    user_membership = UserMembership.objects.create(user=user)
    user_membership.save()

    # create new Task object:
    task = Task.objects.create(usetask=user_membership, title=title)
    task.save()

    # continue code here...
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says your `usertask` field of your `Task` model refers to a `UserMembership`, not a `User` object.

You can use [**`.get_or_create()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) to retrieve, or create such object if it does not yet exists. For example:

```
def myview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usertask, __ = UserMembership.objects.get_or_create(
            user=request.user
        )
        title = request.POST['title']
        task = Task.objects.create(usertask=usertask, title=title)
    task = Task.objects.order_by('-date').filter(
        is_published=True,
        usertask__user=request.user
    )
    context={
        'task':task,
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

You should filter on the `usertask__user=request.user`, since again, a `usertask` will retrieve a `UserMembership` object, not a `User` object.

I strongly advice to work with [*forms* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) and not try to process the `request.POST` querydictionary yourself. It is for example possible that the POST request does *not* contain any value for `title`, which can raise errors. A form will handle that more elegantly.

Comment: How to make a form for this, with django forms?